# How to detect changepoint with a bit of tolerance?

Tags: r, variance, residuals, change-point

I'm using the **changepoint** package in R because I need to check if the variance is stable or if there are some breaks inside. The function **cpt.var** does the job well but there is not a parameter to set the "lags". With lags I mean a parameter to specify how many errors can be accepted before should be consider it a breaks.

Take a look at the image below. The function correctly finds the break(below -2 on the plot) but as you can see the variance of the follow residuals continues constant.

[image: Residuals]

Is there a similar function with the possibility to set the number of "errors" that should be found before considering it a break?

Thank you!

Comment: can you explain a bit more what cpt.var does ? is it some sort of derivative estimate  ? I don't know the package you are using but I think there must be some smoothing parameter somewhere that you can play with and that would be somehow similar to what you want.

Comment: @robin - thank you for your comment, take a look at: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/changepoint/docs/cpt.var

Comment: Yes, reading the docs is really a good advice.
Note however that inside-r.org is unfortunately relatively rarely synchronized with CRAN ... I'd recommend reading the (PDF version of) the reference manual directly off CRAN, e.g. for the ETH Zurich mirror, the PDF at
http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/web/packages/changepoint/

Comment: try test.stat="CSS" or penalty="SIC1". hope it works